# eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC AndEngine Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I m developing a game in And engine which throws the exception. Actually I don't know the point where exceptions occurs. It is reported in market many many time.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1080)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1038)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1364)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

is there any solution for this one??

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: My app was working fine on a Nexus 7 but was failing on a Sony Ericsson Xperia.  I removed the only EGL call I was using (ConfigChooser) and it worked fine on the Xperia.

Comment: can you explain with a piece of code?

Comment: In the constructor of the GLSurfaceView I was calling setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,0,0).  I removed this code and I no longer got the exception so I guess there was something wrong with the config settings I was using. Hope this helps.

Comment: it means you were directly working on GL I am working on AndEngine can you guess where should I put this code?

Comment: Sorry, I am using openGL directly.  I have not had any experience with AndEngine.  Have you already looked into texture size causing the issue?

Comment: No its not the texture size, it some thing else. I am looking into it

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur when you don't notify the GLSurfaceView about state transistions of your Activity.
See the following paragraph from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html

> **Activity Life-cycle**
>
> A GLSurfaceView must be notified when the activity is paused and
>   resumed. GLSurfaceView clients are required to call onPause() when the
>   activity pauses and onResume() when the activity resumes. These calls
>   allow GLSurfaceView to pause and resume the rendering thread, and also
>   allow GLSurfaceView to release and recreate the OpenGL display.

I don't know how andengine handles this though.

Comment: but onpause and onresume are already handled. What else do you suggest??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know about other causes for this error. Notifying GLSurfaceView fixed it for me. If it is any help: Try to recreate it yourself by repeatedly switching between homescreen and your game. This is where the error happened for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (which is specific to my Samsung Note, and no other Android device I've tested so far), is that `EGL_BAD_ALLOC` will be incorrectly produced by `eglSwapBuffers()` instead of `EGL_BAD_CURRENT_SURFACE`.  If your code handles re-creating the surface, it should be trivial to handle this obscure case as well.