# IllegalStateException on HardwareRenderer createSurface

Tags: android

In my crashlytics logs I see following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException eglMakeCurrent failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC  android.view.HardwareRenderer GlRenderer.createSurface HardwareRenderer.java
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.invalidate(HardwareRenderer.java:1328)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1921)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1234)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6467)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.4_r1.2/core/java/android/view/HardwareRenderer.java#L1328

I get this crash for GT I9500 - Android 4.4.2 users.
What would be the cause and how can I isolate the problem ?

(Similar: [Problems with passing variable via intent between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668242/problems-with-passing-variable-via-intent-between-activities)
  [eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC AndEngine Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293241/eglswapbuffers-failed-egl-bad-alloc-andengine-android))

Comment: Similar crashes for an app, and all of them are from Asus MeMO Pad HD 7 (ME173X) (ME173X), 1024MB RAM, Android 4.2

Answer (score 2):

Like the link you mentioned says, First place to look for errors is to ensure that  `onPause` and `onResume` are passed to both your super and to the `GLSurfaceView`

```
...@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLView.onResume();
    }

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;...
```

Comment: Inside `onPause` method I have this: `super.onPause()` but I don't have this: `mGLView.onPause()`. Should I add mGLView?

Comment: This happens to %0.1 of the users. Why is this error happens so rare ?

Comment: @trante Indeed... I just saw it for the first time today.  I have hundreds of enterprise devices that have been running for years.  From time to time I see other really weird errors.  It makes me think that maybe Android's standard API has some race conditions in it.

Answer (score 2):

The following code (for hiding the navigation bar) produces also a `EGL_BAD_ALLOC` on some devices (in my case a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Android 4.2.2):

```
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = window.getAttributes();
attributes.flags |= 0x80000000;
window.setAttributes(attributes);
```

Comment: I am running the same device as you (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Android 4.2.2), and I am getting this exception when setting the DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds flag on a window. Have you solved or made any progress on this?

Comment: did not help for me